# Using Chromium Embedded Framework in an MFC application

Tags: mfc, chromium-embedded

I have refereed to the link http://www.magpcss.net/cef_downloads/ from where I have got a project named `cefclient` and `cefsimple`. I did not receive the source code for the same. I want to do a simple application using this framework. I have been trying to add the .h and .cpp obtained from the files that I have downloaded, but not getting the code working. I am very much new to this and need help to build a very simply application using CEF.

Answer (score 1):

There is a project https://code.google.com/p/cef-mfc/

Basically it is a Visual Studio project that uses Chromium Embedded Framework (CEF) in a Microsoft Foundation Class (MFC) application.

Comment: Thanks for the link, will try and get back

Comment: @ Andrew: The above mentioned link gave me the sample project, but in steps to compile, its mentioned as "Add the CEF project "libcef_dll_wrapper" found in the CEF folder to the CEFMFC project." Now where can I get this project? I tried but not able to find it anywhere. I just got the cpp file of this dll.

Comment: Then go ahead and compile it as DLL